# How to write this in pdfLaTeX? We have to use align

Tags: symbols

I have to write in an assignment for school a list of mathematical symbols, like N, R, the union sign, the not-equal to sign and a couple more. I know all the commands, but how do i get them in my file, with a space between them and centered, without getting an error message?

Just a beginner

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-are-good-learning-resources-for-a-latex-beginner)

Comment: Welcome! What code do you have so far? What error message are you getting? Did you remember to switch to maths mode?

Comment: Here is a number of oft-used symbols
\begin{align*}
\alpha \beta \gamma \delta \epsilon \zeta \eta \theta \kappa \lambda \mu \nu \xi \pi \rho \sigma \tau \phi \psi \omega\\
\leq\! \geq\! \neq\! \cap\! \cup\! \subset\! \supseteq\! \in\! \{\ \} \Rightarrow\! \iff\! \N\! \R\!
\end{align*}

\end{document}

Comment: this is what is have now, we use packages \amsmath \amsthm \amssymb

Comment: i got the following error message ! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...seteq \in \{ \} \Rightarrow \iff \N 
                                                  \R 
l.67 \end{align}
                
?

Comment: the error message you show isn't useful in the form you show -- the point at which the line breaks is very important.  please edit it, as code, into your question (you are always able to edit your own question).  it might be helpful to also show the input file there -- it shouldn't be very long.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're doing something similar to [The Comprehensive LATEX Symbol List](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/comprehensive?lang=en).  If you look through the [source](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/source) for that document, here's how they format their tables (`Negated Harpoons` table on page 81 copied here):

```
\begin{symtable}[MNS]{\MNS\ Negated Harpoons}
\index{harpoons}
\index{restrictions}
\label{mns-nharpoons}
\begin{tabular}{*3{ll}}
\K[\MNSndownharpoonccw]\ndownharpoonccw$^*$             & \K[\MNSnneswharpoons]\nneswharpoons           & \K[\MNSnseharpooncw]\nseharpooncw                       \\
\K[\MNSndownharpooncw]\ndownharpooncw$^*$               & \K[\MNSnneswharpoonsenw]\nneswharpoonsenw     & \K[\MNSnsenwharpoons]\nsenwharpoons                     \\
\K[\MNSndownupharpoons]\ndownupharpoons                 & \K[\MNSnnwharpoonccw]\nnwharpoonccw           & \K[\MNSnswharpoonccw]\nswharpoonccw                     \\
\K[\MNSnleftharpoonccw]\nleftharpoonccw$^*$             & \K[\MNSnnwharpooncw]\nnwharpooncw             & \K[\MNSnswharpooncw]\nswharpooncw                       \\
\K[\MNSnleftharpooncw]\nleftharpooncw$^*$               & \K[\MNSnnwseharpoonnesw]\nnwseharpoonnesw     & \K[\MNSnswneharpoons]\nswneharpoons                     \\
\K[\MNSnleftrightharpoondownup]\nleftrightharpoondownup & \K[\MNSnnwseharpoons]\nnwseharpoons           & \K[\MNSnupdownharpoonleftright]\nupdownharpoonleftright \\
\K[\MNSnleftrightharpoons]\nleftrightharpoons           & \K[\MNSnnwseharpoonswne]\nnwseharpoonswne     & \K[\MNSnupdownharpoonrightleft]\nupdownharpoonrightleft \\
\K[\MNSnleftrightharpoonupdown]\nleftrightharpoonupdown & \K[\MNSnrightharpoonccw]\nrightharpoonccw$^*$ & \K[\MNSnupdownharpoons]\nupdownharpoons                 \\
\K[\MNSnneharpoonccw]\nneharpoonccw                     & \K[\MNSnrightharpooncw]\nrightharpooncw$^*$   & \K[\MNSnupharpoonccw]\nupharpoonccw$^*$                 \\
\K[\MNSnneharpooncw]\nneharpooncw                       & \K[\MNSnrightleftharpoons]\nrightleftharpoons & \K[\MNSnupharpooncw]\nupharpooncw$^*$                   \\
\K[\MNSnneswharpoonnwse]\nneswharpoonnwse               & \K[\MNSnseharpoonccw]\nseharpoonccw           &                                                         \\
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tablenote}[*]
  Where marked, the ``\verb|ccw|'' suffix can be replaced with
  ``\verb|up|'' and the ``\verb|cw|'' suffix can be replaced with
  ``\verb|down|''.  (In addition, \cmdI[\MNSnupharpooncw]{\nupharpooncw}
  can be written as \cmdI[\MNSnupharpooncw]{\nrestriction}.)
\end{tablenote}
\end{symtable}
```

This won't compile if you copy it directly (they have some custom stuff defined), but it should give you a good point to build from.